# Using eigendecomposition to transform state vector in linear Gaussian state space model

Tags: covariance-matrix, state-space-models

Paper: [A Unifying Review of Linear Gaussian Models](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eroweis/papers/lds.pdf) by Roweis & Ghahramani

The generative model is the typical state space model written as
\begin{align}
\text{state transition equation: }{\bf x}_t &= {\bf A} {\bf x}_{t-1} + {\bf w}_t && {\bf w}_t \sim \mathcal{N} \left( {\bf 0}, {\bf Q} \right) \\
\text{observation equation: }{\bf y}_t &= {\bf C} {\bf x}_t + {\bf v}_t && {\bf v}_t \sim \mathcal{N} \left( {\bf 0}, {\bf R} \right)
\end{align}
where ${\bf A}$ is the $k \times k$ state transition matrix and ${\bf C}$ is the $p \times k$ observation matrix.

In the paper on. page 2, the authors write

> Notice that there is degeneracy in the model: all of the structure in the matrix $\bf Q$ can be moved into the matrices $\bf A$ and $\bf C$. This means we can without loss generality work with models in which $\bf Q$ is the identity matrix.

There is a footnote associated with the passage and it reads

> In particular, since is it a covariance matrix, $\bf Q$ is symmetric positive semi-definite and thus can be diagonalized to the form $\bf E \Lambda E^{\top}$ (where $\bf E$ is the rotation matrix of eigenvectors and ${\bf \Lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues). Thus for any model in which $\bf Q$ is not the identity matrix, we can generate an *exactly equivalent* model using a new state vector ${\bf x}' = {\bf \Lambda}^{-1/2} {\bf E}^{\top} {\bf x}$ with ${\bf A}' = ( {\bf \Lambda}^{-1/2} {\bf E}^{\top} ) \, {\bf A} \, ( {\bf E} {\bf \Lambda}^{1/2} )$ and ${\bf C}' = {\bf C} ( {\bf E} {\bf \Lambda}^{1/2})$ such that the new covariance of ${\bf x}'$ is the identity matrix: ${\bf Q}' = {\bf I}$.

**Question:** Must we make an assumption that $\bf Q$ is known in order to do what the authors are suggesting? If $\bf Q$ is unknown, then how can we use it's eigendecomposition to transform $\bf x \rightarrow \bf x'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Must we make an assumption that $\mathbf{Q}$ is known in order to do
> what the authors are suggesting?

No, this is a matter of identifiability, and things like this are commonly done to make the model identifiable. A restriction is put on the parameter space to rule out alternative parameter vector estimates.

> If $\mathbf{Q}$ is unknown, then how can we use it's eigendecomposition
> to transform...

You are doing it theoretically, not with real numbers or estimates.

Side note: I don't like the authors' use of the word degeneracy. (Particle) degeneracy is an issue with particle filtering algorithms, which are used for state space models, as well.

Comment: Ah... So we are allowed to do what the authors suggest due to the fact that, theoretically, the simplifying transformation always exists.

Comment: I realized some problems in my previous comment. The simplifying transformation from the paper does not always exists. If $\bf Q$ is not positive definite, then ${\bf \Lambda}^{-1/2}$ does not exist because one or more eigenvalues are zero. I have to be careful.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt yes, sometimes $\mathbf{Q}$ is not full rank (e.g. when the state vector is augmented with lagged variables, the transitions for most of the elements of the vector are noiseless)